# Sticky notes with local storage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using this codepen https://codepen.io/ravitadi/pen/CsIFL and I would like to add another field for the user to input a title for the note.

I am a javascript noobie and I can't seem to get it right. This is the function for adding notes. The full script is in the [codepen](https://codepen.io/ravitadi/pen/CsIFL).

```
function addNote(){
     var usrInput = $('.txtBox').val();
     //console.log(usrInput);

    if(usrInput.length > 0){
        console.log($(this));
        $('#').removeClass('ntActv');
        addtoSticky(usrInput);
        cnclOvrly();
        //console.log(notes);
    }else{

    }
}


function addtoSticky(note){
    if(note.length > 0){
        console.log(note);
        createSticky(note);
        localStorage.setItem('note_'+note.length, note);
    }
}

function createSticky(text){
    $('#stkyNts').append('<li class="box">'+text+'</li>');
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/ravitadi/pen/CsIFL)

Comment: You need to follow the same steps as it is mentioned for the sticky note. Do try and if you stuck then post the problem on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to update following your requirement.

You should change way to save object and load object from localstorage.

```
storedNotes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes"));

if(current == null) current = [];
        current.push(JSON.stringify(note));
        localStorage.setItem('notes', JSON.stringify(current));
```

https://codepen.io/viethien/pen/RdqKxM

Comment: Works, in the first instance, but when reloaded the local storage returns "undefined-undefined" for both the title and the text box.

Comment: Please delete your localstorage by f12 and go to application tab, I changed way to store

Comment: @mateicoman Unfair of you changing the accepted answer. I did give you a heads up on where to change.

Answer (score 2):

In the modal, add another text box for title before the textarea.

```html
<!-- add this -->
<input type="text" id="title" />
<!-- /add this -->
<textarea class="txtBox"></textarea>
```

Now you have to grab the value from the title. In the `createSticky()` function:

```
function createSticky(text) {
  var heading = $("#title").val();
  $('#stkyNts').append('<li class="box"><h3>' + heading + '</h3>'+text+'</li>');
}
```

And there you go:

[image: preview]

For the extended functionality, try to change the way, `heading` is included in the local storage while setting and getting it. For doing so, you need to include the `heading` in the functions `addtoSticky()` and `getStoredNotes()`.